# NSTimer is not working fine ..in Animation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, device, nstimer

im new to iPhone programming..in my app the timer is not working fine.
can anybody help me out please...
The following is the code for animating few images wn we touch or swipe..they fall down

i want to restrict the touches for few seconds with use of timer...
is there another way to do this..?(before using timer its crashing on device,but working fine in the simulator..im trying for solution for crashing..)

```
//  HomeViewController.m


#import "HomeViewController.h"

@implementation HomeViewController

@synthesize dustImage, myAnimatedView;

@synthesize _isAnimating = isAnimating;

float ver_X, ver_Y;
BOOL rotated;
NSTimer *touchTimer;


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.frame  = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    //[self playAudio];

}

-(void)blowingTheSparkles:(NSSet *) touches {

    if(!isAnimating){
        float a, aa; 
        float b, bb;

        CGRect frame1;
        myAnimatedView = [UIImageView alloc];

        //NSLog(@"touch count...%d",[touches count]);
        for (int i=0; i< (int)[touches count]; ++i) {
            UITouch* touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:dustImage];

            NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"starburst1.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"starburst2.png"], 
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"starburst3.png"], 
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"starburst4.gif"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"starburst5.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"starburst6.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"starburst7.png"],nil]; 
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200
            a=(location.x)-80;
            b=(location.y)-80;
            ver_X=768;
            ver_Y=1024;     

            frame1 = CGRectMake(a,b,160,160);

#else

            a=(location.x)-40;
            b=(location.y)-40;
            ver_X=320;
            ver_Y=480;

            frame1 = CGRectMake(a,b,80,80);

#endif
            aa= location.x;
            bb= location.y;
            [myAnimatedView initWithFrame:frame1]; 
            myAnimatedView.animationImages = myImages; 
            myAnimatedView.animationDuration = 0.25;
            myAnimatedView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

            [dustImage addSubview:myAnimatedView];


            CABasicAnimation *fadeOutAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
            [fadeOutAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3]];
            fadeOutAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
            fadeOutAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

            //Set up scaling
            CABasicAnimation *resizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size"];
            [resizeAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(0.0f, frame1.size.height * (1.0f /1.0))]];
            resizeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
            resizeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

            // Set up path movement
            CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
            pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
            pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
            pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

            CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(aa ,ver_Y);
            CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
            CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, aa, bb);
            CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, endPoint.x, bb,endPoint.x, bb,endPoint.x,endPoint.y);
            pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
            CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

            CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation]; 
            group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
            group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
            [group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fadeOutAnimation, pathAnimation, resizeAnimation, nil]];
            group.duration = 4.0f;
            group.delegate = self;
            [group setValue:myAnimatedView forKey:@"myAnimatedView"];

            [myAnimatedView.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"savingAnimation"];
            [myAnimatedView startAnimating];


        }   
    }
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(!isAnimating)
        [self blowingTheSparkles:touches];

}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
}


-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    isAnimating=TRUE;
    touchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(sleeping) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)sleeping{

    NSLog(@"....Hiiii");
    isAnimating = FALSE;
    [touchTimer invalidate];
    touchTimer = nil;

}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if(!isAnimating){
        [self blowingTheSparkles:touches];

        }

}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return NO;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];   

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [super viewDidUnload];

}


- (void)dealloc {

    [myAnimatedView release];

    [super dealloc];

}

@end
```

Comment: Any logs from the crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be correctly retaining the NSTimer which could be your problem here.

Change it to:

```
touchTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(sleeping) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];
```

Ideally you should declare touchTimer as a property and synthesize it, but try this first.

Change sleeping to release the timer:

```
-(void)sleeping{

    NSLog(@"....Hiiii");
    isAnimating = FALSE;
    [touchTimer invalidate];
    [touchTimer release];
    touchTimer = nil;
}
```